# Spring Boot not working with dependent application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, maven-resources-plugin, spring-boot-starter

I'm working with the Spring Boot 2.2.9.RELEASE. I have the main app and some plain starter (which just uses `spring-actuator` functionality) with some properties in its `some-starter/src/main/resources/application.properties` file:

```
management.server.port=9000
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=health
```

I've imported the starter into my main app and I believe that the healthcheck endpoint should work with the port `9000` and with the path `/health` (smth like that `localhost:9000/health`).

But it doesn't. However, it works in case of the same properties in my main app `main-app/src/main/resources/application.properties`.

Is it problem with the property overriding in Spring Boot? Should i configure my resources via something like `maven-resources-plugin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `application.properties` is loaded from the classpath, the first one on the classpath is loaded and any others on the classpath are ignored. In your case, the file in `main-app/src/main/resources/application.properties` will appear on the classpath before the `application.properties` in the jar of `some-starter`.

As its name suggests, `application.properties` is intended for configuring your application and it shouldn't be used in a starter. You should either configure all of the properties in your application, or you could update your starter to include an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that is registered via `spring.factories` and adds some default properties to the `Environment`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm going to check the  `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. Nevertheless, what if i'd like to add some properties to my starter/library without any additional code. Should i use another name for property file or it's possible to merge main and 3rd party properties?